# how to re-style menu for mobile view using @media

Tags: css, media-queries

I worked hard to get this menu running on my page but I'm still struggling with the mobile view.

I would like to style it like most classic navigations, like this one:

mobile menu with 100% width and one item per line

[image]

I tried:

```
@media (max-width :899px){
.site-nav {
display: block;
width: 100%;
```

But that had no effect on the flex items.

Would one be so kind and give me a hint where to start?

[here is also a link to a pen](https://codepen.io/undefined999/pen/GMPOQY)

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

  // add JS-classes into the HTML-Tag
  $('html').addClass('js');

  // add classes for sub menus and sub menus toggle button
  $(".site-nav li > ul").parent('li').addClass('has-sub-menu');
  $(".site-nav li > ul").addClass('sub-menu');

  // create button for expand- und collapse the menu and render it into the header
  var create_toggle_nav_button = ['<div class="toggle-site-nav">Menu</div>'].join("");
  $("header").append(create_toggle_nav_button); 

  // create button for expand- und collapse the sub menu  for mobile view and add them to all sub menus
  var create_sub_toggle_button = ['<span class="toggle-sub-menu"></span>'].join("");
  $(".has-sub-menu > a").after(create_sub_toggle_button);

  // define variables
  var $menu = $('.site-nav'),
  $toggle_nav = $('.toggle-site-nav'),
  $toggle_sub_menu = $('.toggle-sub-menu');

  // collapse and expand function of the main menu
  $toggle_nav.click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $menu.slideToggle();
  });

  // collapse and expand function of the drop down menu for mobile view
  $toggle_sub_menu.click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').slideToggle();
  });

  // display hidden elements again, when browserwindow is resized by user
  $(window).resize(function(){
    var w = $(window).width();
    if(w > 900) {
     $('.site-nav').removeAttr('style');
     $('.sub-menu').removeAttr('style');
    }
    });

    // collapse navigation automatically to the left, when it run out of the viewport
  $(".site-nav .has-sub-menu").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (e) {

         var nav_element = $('ul:first', this);
         var element_offset = nav_element .offset();
         var element_offset_left = element_offset.left;
         var element_width = nav_element.width();
         var viewport_width = $(window).width();

         var element_in_viewport = (element_offset_left + element_width <= viewport_width);
                  
         if ( ! element_in_viewport ) {
             $(this).addClass('sub-left');
         } else {
             $(this).removeClass('sub-left');
         }
     });
  
});
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
 padding:0;
 list-style:none;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

body::after {
 content:'';
 position: fixed;
 bottom:1em;
 right:1em;
 opacity: 0.5;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 z-index: 10;
}

header {
 width:100%;
 background: white;
}

.container {
 max-width:1000px;
 margin:0 auto;
 }

.logo {
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 padding:1em;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:gray; /* ? */
}

.site-nav {
 z-index: 10;
}

.site-nav>ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: auto;
}

.site-nav >ul> li {
 display: inline-block;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:auto;
  padding:0;
}

.site-nav a {
 display:inline-flex;
  align-content: stretch;
  padding:1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
 text-decoration:none;
  height:100%;
 width:100%;
 color:white;     /* text color of all */
 background:#5a595a; /* background color main nav Link 1 */
 border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 z-index: 10;
}

.site-nav a:hover {
 background:#8c8e94; /* mouseover color Link 1 and Link 1.1 opacity */
}

.js .site-nav {
 display:none;
}

.js .sub-menu {
 display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0px;
  z-index: 12;
}

.js .sub-menu .sub-menu {
  top:0px;
  right:100%;
  left:auto;
  text-align:right;
}

  .js .has-sub-menu { 
  position:relative;
  top:100%;
  left:0px;
}

.sub-menu li:last-of-type {
 padding-bottom:0;
}

.sub-menu a {
 background:#676567; /* background color menu 2.1 only */
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu a {
 background:#747274; /* background color menu 2.1.1 only */
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu a:hover {
 background:#8c8e94; /* mouseover color Link 1 and Link 1.1 */
}

/* toggles */

.toggle-site-nav {
 background:#5a595a; /* background color of menu button when resized */
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 padding:1em;
 color:white; /* text color of the word menu in menu button when resized */
 cursor:pointer;
 z-index: 10;
}

.toggle-site-nav:hover {
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* mouseover color of menu button when resized */
}

.toggle-sub-menu {
 display:none;
}

.js .toggle-sub-menu {
 display:flex;
  position:absolute;
  align-content: center;
  right:0em;
  top:1.05em; /* hight of the borders */
 background:#817e81; /* backgound of annoying squares when resized */
 height: 15px;
 width: 15px;
 cursor:pointer;
  z-index: 11;
}

.js .toggle-sub-menu.active {
 background: #DCDCDC; /* color of annoying square after clicking on it when resized */
}
 
.toggle-sub-menu:hover,
.toggle-sub-menu.active:hover  {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* mouseover of annoying squares when resized */
}

@media screen and (min-width:900px) {
 
 .logo {
  width:auto;
  float:left; 
 }
 
 .site-nav {
  width:auto;
  display: flex !important;
 }

 .site-nav a {
  border:none;
 }
 
 .site-nav li {
  width:auto;
  padding:0;
 }

 .site-nav li:hover {
  background:rgba(52,50,52,1); /* mouseover background color of all menu */
 }

 .has-sub-menu a {
  padding-right: 2em; /* check this value */
 }

 .has-sub-menu:after { /* check this for editing the stripes */
  display:flex;
    content:'';
  position: absolute;
    align-content: center;
  top:1.1em;
  right: 0;
  width:1em;
  height:30%;
  background:#817e81; /* color of stripes in main menu when it has submenu */
 }

 /* sub menu */
 .site-nav li:hover > .sub-menu {
  display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px; /* width of sub menus */
    padding: 0 25px 25px 25px;
    left: -25px;
 }

 .sub-menu {display:none;}
 
 .sub-menu li {
  width:100%; 
 }
 
 .sub-menu > a {
  width:100%;
  display:block; 
 }

 .has-sub-menu .has-sub-menu:after {
  background:#817e81; /* color of stripes of Link 2.1 menu when it has submenu */
 }
 
 .has-sub-menu .has-sub-menu:hover .sub-menu {
  display:block; 
  position:absolute;
    width: 300px; /* width of subsub menues */
    padding: 0 25px 25px 25px;
    left: 224px;
    top: 0px;
 }
 
 .toggle-site-nav,
 .toggle-sub-menu {
  display:none !important; 
 }

 /* navigations items, which collapse to the left */

 .sub-left > .sub-menu {
  left:auto;
  right:0;
 }

 .site-nav .sub-menu .sub-left > .sub-menu {
  left:-275px;
 }
}


@media (max-width :899px){
  .site-nav {
    z-index: 13;
    margin-top: 19px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="container">

    <a href="#" class="logo"></a>
    <nav class="site-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2.1</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2.1.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2.1.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2.1.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2.1.4</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2.1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">loooooong</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">loooooooooooooooooong</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3.5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 7</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.3</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7.3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7.3.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">loooooooong</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7.3.4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7.3.5</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: `.site-nav` is not the only flex item, the UL in it is also flex. Plus the LI are inline-block ... so you will have to overwrite a few more styles. (Hint: Use browser dev tools, there you can see what style applies to what elements.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 899px){
.site-nav>ul {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
.site-nav >ul> li {
    display: block !important;
    width: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

  // add JS-classes into the HTML-Tag
  $('html').addClass('js');

  // add classes for sub menus and sub menus toggle button
  $(".site-nav li > ul").parent('li').addClass('has-sub-menu');
  $(".site-nav li > ul").addClass('sub-menu');

  // create button for expand- und collapse the menu and render it into the header
  var create_toggle_nav_button = ['<div class="toggle-site-nav">Menu</div>'].join("");
  $("header").append(create_toggle_nav_button); 

  // create button for expand- und collapse the sub menu  for mobile view and add them to all sub menus
  var create_sub_toggle_button = ['<span class="toggle-sub-menu"></span>'].join("");
  $(".has-sub-menu > a").after(create_sub_toggle_button);

  // define variables
  var $menu = $('.site-nav'),
  $toggle_nav = $('.toggle-site-nav'),
  $toggle_sub_menu = $('.toggle-sub-menu');

  // collapse and expand function of the main menu
  $toggle_nav.click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $menu.slideToggle();
  });

  // collapse and expand function of the drop down menu for mobile view
  $toggle_sub_menu.click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').slideToggle();
  });

  // display hidden elements again, when browserwindow is resized by user
  $(window).resize(function(){
    var w = $(window).width();
    if(w > 900) {
     $('.site-nav').removeAttr('style');
     $('.sub-menu').removeAttr('style');
    }
    });

    // collapse navigation automatically to the left, when it run out of the viewport
  $(".site-nav .has-sub-menu").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (e) {

         var nav_element = $('ul:first', this);
         var element_offset = nav_element .offset();
         var element_offset_left = element_offset.left;
         var element_width = nav_element.width();
         var viewport_width = $(window).width();

         var element_in_viewport = (element_offset_left + element_width <= viewport_width);
                  
         if ( ! element_in_viewport ) {
             $(this).addClass('sub-left');
         } else {
             $(this).removeClass('sub-left');
         }
     });
  
});
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
 padding:0;
 list-style:none;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

body::after {
 content:'';
 position: fixed;
 bottom:1em;
 right:1em;
 opacity: 0.5;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 z-index: 10;
}

header {
 width:100%;
 background: white;
}

.container {
 max-width:1000px;
 margin:0 auto;
 }

.logo {
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 padding:1em;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:gray; /* ? */
}

.site-nav {
 z-index: 10;
}

.site-nav>ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: auto;
}

.site-nav >ul> li {
 display: inline-block;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:auto;
  padding:0;
}

.site-nav a {
 display:inline-flex;
  align-content: stretch;
  padding:1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
 text-decoration:none;
  height:100%;
 width:100%;
 color:white;     /* text color of all */
 background:#5a595a; /* background color main nav Link 1 */
 border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 z-index: 10;
}

.site-nav a:hover {
 background:#8c8e94; /* mouseover color Link 1 and Link 1.1 opacity */
}

.js .site-nav {
 display:none;
}

.js .sub-menu {
 display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0px;
  z-index: 12;
}

.js .sub-menu .sub-menu {
  top:0px;
  right:100%;
  left:auto;
  text-align:right;
}

  .js .has-sub-menu { 
  position:relative;
  top:100%;
  left:0px;
}

.sub-menu li:last-of-type {
 padding-bottom:0;
}

.sub-menu a {
 background:#676567; /* background color menu 2.1 only */
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu a {
 background:#747274; /* background color menu 2.1.1 only */
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu a:hover {
 background:#8c8e94; /* mouseover color Link 1 and Link 1.1 */
}

/* toggles */

.toggle-site-nav {
 background:#5a595a; /* background color of menu button when resized */
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 padding:1em;
 color:white; /* text color of the word menu in menu button when resized */
 cursor:pointer;
 z-index: 10;
}

.toggle-site-nav:hover {
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* mouseover color of menu button when resized */
}

.toggle-sub-menu {
 display:none;
}

.js .toggle-sub-menu {
 display:flex;
  position:absolute;
  align-content: center;
  right:0em;
  top:1.05em; /* hight of the borders */
 background:#817e81; /* backgound of annoying squares when resized */
 height: 15px;
 width: 15px;
 cursor:pointer;
  z-index: 11;
}

.js .toggle-sub-menu.active {
 background: #DCDCDC; /* color of annoying square after clicking on it when resized */
}
 
.toggle-sub-menu:hover,
.toggle-sub-menu.active:hover  {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* mouseover of annoying squares when resized */
}

@media screen and (min-width:900px) {
 
 .logo {
  width:auto;
  float:left; 
 }
 
 .site-nav {
  width:auto;
  display: flex !important;
 }

 .site-nav a {
  border:none;
 }
 
 .site-nav li {
  width:auto;
  padding:0;
 }

 .site-nav li:hover {
  background:rgba(52,50,52,1); /* mouseover background color of all menu */
 }

 .has-sub-menu a {
  padding-right: 2em; /* check this value */
 }

 .has-sub-menu:after { /* check this for editing the stripes */
  display:flex;
    content:'';
  position: absolute;
    align-content: center;
  top:1.1em;
  right: 0;
  width:1em;
  height:30%;
  background:#817e81; /* color of stripes in main menu when it has submenu */
 }

 /* sub menu */
 .site-nav li:hover > .sub-menu {
  display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px; /* width of sub menus */
    padding: 0 25px 25px 25px;
    left: -25px;
 }

 .sub-menu {display:none;}
 
 .sub-menu li {
  width:100%; 
 }
 
 .sub-menu > a {
  width:100%;
  display:block; 
 }

 .has-sub-menu .has-sub-menu:after {
  background:#817e81; /* color of stripes of Link 2.1 menu when it has submenu */
 }
 
 .has-sub-menu .has-sub-menu:hover .sub-menu {
  display:block; 
  position:absolute;
    width: 300px; /* width of subsub menues */
    padding: 0 25px 25px 25px;
    left: 224px;
    top: 0px;
 }
 
 .toggle-site-nav,
 .toggle-sub-menu {
  display:none !important; 
 }

 /* navigations items, which collapse to the left */

 .sub-left > .sub-menu {
  left:auto;
  right:0;
 }

 .site-nav .sub-menu .sub-left > .sub-menu {
  left:-275px;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 899px){
 .site-nav>ul {   
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: auto;
 }
 .site-nav >ul> li {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:auto;
  padding:0;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="container">

    <a href="#" class="logo"></a>
    <nav class="site-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2.1</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2.1.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2.1.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2.1.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2.1.4</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2.1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">loooooong</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">loooooooooooooooooong</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3.5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 7</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.3</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7.3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7.3.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">loooooooong</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7.3.4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7.3.5</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: thank you Hardi I tried your suggestion but it didnt work. But still thank you for your time :)